# Comparing strings with Python: X in ['item1', 'item2', ...] vs. X == 'item1', X == 'item2', ...?

Tags: python, string, performance, list, comparison

I am fairly new to Python and I have a question regarding performance when comparing strings. Both codes below seem to achieve what I want but is there any reason to use one of them instead of the other?

Option1:

```
if first_column_header == 'author name' or first_column_header == 'author' or first_column_header == 'name':
```

Option2:

```
if first_column_header in ['author name', 'author', 'name']:
```

Comment: try it using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 2 is definitely shorter and more pythonic. It's also possible that it adds a little more of overhead to your code because it creates a list and then iterates through it.

This is a trade off you'll have to accept by making programs more readable but, IMHO, **this is too little overhead to worry** so I'll go with Option 2.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a *lot* of choices, say more than a dozen, and speed is *really* critical, then use a `set`. It's the fastest to check membership, although there's some overhead since the item being checked needs to be hashed. Define the set ahead of time so it's not redefined each time the `if` statement is executed.

```
first_column_names  = {"author name", "author", "name"}

# In Python before 2.7, you must use `set()` instead:
first_column_names = set(("author name", "author", "name"))

if first_column_header in first_column_names:
```

But if speed is critical, what are you writing it in Python for to begin with?  :-)  Generally you'll want to go with what's more readable. In this situation, that'll be a list or a tuple. Defining a tuple literal is marginally faster so, with readability being equal, I'd go that way:

```
if first_column_header in ("author name", "author", "name"):
```

Comment: +1 Good point on redefinition each time `if` statement is executed. Also I measured the two Options withe `timeit` as suggested in a comment and they take **too little time** both so I think this should be on readability more than performance.

Answer (score 1):

I have to disagree with Paulo on the fact that Option 1 is faster. Here is what dis shows for these 2 functions:

```
def t():
    if a == 'author name' or a == 'author' or a == 'name':
        return True
    return False

def t2():
    if a in ['author name','author','name']:
        return True
    return False
```

It seems that a is loaded many times in the first case, and that the list in option 2 is created before the call.

```
3           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('author name') 
              6 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        36 
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               2 ('author') 
             18 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
             21 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        36 
             24 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a) 
             27 LOAD_CONST               3 ('name') 
             30 COMPARE_OP               2 (==) 
             33 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       40 

  4     >>   36 LOAD_CONST               4 (True) 
             39 RETURN_VALUE         

  5     >>   40 LOAD_CONST               5 (False) 
             43 RETURN_VALUE         
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (a) 
              3 LOAD_CONST               4 (('author name', 'author', 'name')) 
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in) 
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       16 

  9          12 LOAD_CONST               5 (True) 
             15 RETURN_VALUE         

 10     >>   16 LOAD_CONST               6 (False) 
             19 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I measure them and was surprised to see that they perform almost exact. But as I was suggesting, takes so little time that it's more about readability than speed.